# How to create a form that generates a pdf and saves to a mongoDB without using PHP

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, pdf

I'm just going to be collecting demographic information from end users who will be registering for my Aunt's Driver's Ed class. I will be changing the starter code below to reflect that. It would be helpful if the information they enter was put into a pdf form in which the students can print off, sign (or e-sign) and bring to class. It would also be helpful if we had this information stored somewhere so that we the students come to class we could print it off for them if they forgot. In this case, I can see that I need a database. But what do I need to connect it to the form and create a pdf? I would like to use MEAN stack if possible. PHP is not an option.

This is the starter code that I will be using:

```css
.register-form {
 line-height: 1.4;
}
.form-group {
 background: #F6DDCE;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
 padding: 10px;
}
.form-group ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0 0 2em;
 padding: 0;
}
.form-group li {
 margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.form-group h3 {
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.form-fields input[type="text"],
.form-fields input[type="tel"],
.form-fields input[type="url"],
.form-fields input[type="email"],
.form-fields input[type="number"],
.form-fields select {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.6em 0.8em;
  color: #999;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: normal;
  max-height: 3em;
}
.form-fields input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-fields input[type="tel"]:focus,
.form-fields input[type="url"]:focus,
.form-fields input[type="email"]:focus,
.form-fields input[type="number"]:focus,
.form-food textarea:focus,
.form-fields select:focus {
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #C17CCF;
  outline: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.form-food textarea {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font: 0.9em Lato, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 90%;
    height: 6em;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0.6em 0.8em;
    color: #999;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    line-height: normal;
}
.register-btn {
 border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 background: #8B798C;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: white;
 padding: 0.35em 0.75em;
 border: none;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer; 
}
.register-btn:hover, .register-btn:focus {
 background: #C17CCF;
}
/*flex it*/
.register-form {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.form-group {
 flex: 1 0 300px;
}
.form-submit {
 flex: 0 0 100%;
}
.form-fields li {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.form-fields input[type="text"],
.form-fields input[type="tel"],
.form-fields input[type="url"],
.form-fields input[type="email"],
.form-fields input[type="number"],
.form-fields select {
 flex: 1 0 230px;
}
.form-fields label {
 flex: 1 0 90px;
 max-width: 200px;
}
.form-skills, .form-workshop {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.form-skills li {
 width: 145px;
}
.form-workshop li {
```

```html
<form class="register-form">
<section class="form-group">
<h3>Personal Info</h3>
<ul class="form-fields">
<li><label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="your full name" class="text-input"></li>
<li><label for="street-address">Street address:</label> <input type="text" name="street-address" id="street-address" placeholder="your street address" class="text-input"></li>
<li><label for="city">City:</label> <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="city" class="text-input"></li>
<li><label for="state">State:</label> <select class="select-menu" id="state" name="state">
 <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
 <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
 <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
 <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
 <option value="CA">California</option>
 <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
 <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
 <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
 <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
 <option value="FL">Florida</option>
 <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
 <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
 <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
 <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
 <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
 <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
 <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
 <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
 <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
 <option value="ME">Maine</option>
 <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
 <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
 <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
 <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
 <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
 <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
 <option value="MT">Montana</option>
 <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
 <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
 <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
 <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
 <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
 <option value="NY">New York</option>
 <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
 <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
 <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
 <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
 <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
 <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
 <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
 <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
 <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
 <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
 <option value="TX">Texas</option>
 <option value="UT">Utah</option>
 <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
 <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
 <option value="WA">Washington</option>
 <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
 <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
 <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select> </li>
<li><label for="street-address">Zip code:</label> <input type="text" name="zip-code" id="zip-code" placeholder="zip code" class="text-input"></li>
<li><label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="confirmation email" class="text-input"></li>
</ul>
<h4>Registration Info</h4>
<p>This info will be on your badge and help us match you with information and events throughout the conference.
<ul class="form-fields">
<li><label for="description">Primary role:</label> <select class="select-menu" id="description" name="description">
 <option value="designer">Designer</option>
 <option value="developer">Developer</option>
 <option value="other">Other</option>
 </select></li>
<li><label for="job-title">Job title:</label> <input type="text" name="job-title" id="job-title" placeholder="job title" class="text-input"></li>
<li><label for="company">Company:</label> <input type="text" name="company" id="company" placeholder="company" class="text-input"></li>
<li><label for="phone">Phone:</label> <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="your phone number" class="text-input"></li>
</ul>
</section>
<section class="form-group">
<h3>Sessions</h3>
<h4>Skills</h4>
<p>Listing skills will help us match up our break out sessions and lunch!</p>
<ul class="form-skills">
<li><input type="checkbox" id="css" value="css"> <label for="css">CSS</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="html" value="html"> <label for="html">HTML</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="js" value="js"> <label for="js">JavaScript</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="content" value="content"> <label for="content">Content Strategy</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="ux" value="ux"> <label for="ux">UX</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="rails" value="rails"> <label for="rails">Rails</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="node" value="node"> <label for="node">Node</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="sass" value="sass"> <label for="sass">SASS</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="mobile" value="mobile"> <label for="mobile">Mobile</label></li>
</ul>
<h4>Workshops</h4>
<p>Workshops are half-day, hands-on classes. Each are an additional $50.</p>
<ul class="form-workshop">
<li><input type="checkbox" id="forms-ws" value="forms"> <label for="forms-ws">Creating Responsive Forms with Flexbox</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="jekyll-ws" value="jekyll"> <label for="jekyll-ws">Blogging with Jekyll</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="usability-ws" value="usability"> <label for="usability-ws">Usability Testing with Cats</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="node-ws" value="node"> <label for="node-ws">Building Stuff with Node</label></li>
</ul>
<h4>Lunch</h4>
<p>Lunch is provided each day. We have vegetarian options as well as gluten-free choices available. Please let us know about any food allergies or dietary restrictions.</p>
<ul class="form-food">
<li><input type="radio" id="meat" value="meat" name="food"> <label for="meat">Chicken, Beef, or Fish</label></li>
<li><input type="radio" id="vegetarian" value="vegetarian" name="food"> <label for="vegetarian">Vegetarian</label></li>
<li><input type="radio" id="gluten" value="gluten" name="food"> <label for="gluten">Gluten Free</label></li>
<li><label for="food-options">Please list any dietary restrictions:</label><textarea id="food-options" name="food-options" class="text-area">food allergies or other restrictions</textarea> </li>
</ul>
</section>
<section class="form-submit">
<h4>All finished?</h4>
<p>We're looking forward to seeing you!</p>
<button type="submit" class="register-btn">Register</button>
</section>
</form>
```

Comment: Way Too broad..

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Can you point me in the direction in what I need to do to get started?

Comment: Learn some basics of node and express.js then try you will be able to do it

Comment: Alright I'll give it a shot. Thanks. @ArpitSolanki

Comment: I'll post an solution too after I'm done because I'm sure others will want to know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've setup a Node.js server using the Express framework, configured MongoDB with mongoose, and setup your models, the flow would be something like:

1. User fills out forms and submits it to the Express server.
2. The form submits to some route handler (controller) function.
3. Inside the controller you'd generate the PDF and save the data to the database.

So the code would be something like:

```
const PDFDocument  = require('pdfkit')

exports.createPdf = async (req, res) => {
  // Save form data to the database
  const myModel = new myModel(req.body)
  await myModel.save()

  const document = new PDFDocument()
  // PDF generation logic...
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I'm not looking for the exact code and your answer gives me the guidelines I need to figure out how to configure this. This provides a solution to my question. It is a broad question but because I'm learning there's a lot I don't know. But I can use the breadcrumbs to piece it together. Thank you very much this helps a lot!